# How to: Get JQuery Delegates to work on "abnormal" action elements in Chrome & other mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates

I use jquery .on delegates to perform events when an item is clicked and in the desktop browser of the site it works. However on viewing a mobile browser such as Chrome they only work on A tags with a href filled in (usually "#"). Div tags can't be tapped in the mobile version.

```
$("body").on("click", ".nav", function () {}); //etc
```

I really don't understand why mobile browsers don't recognize these actions as tapable.

Comment: A demo where you recreate the problem would really help us debug it ourselves! Think you can make one on http://JSFiddle.net?

Comment: check out http://social.standupandpray.com/register and click the "cancel" button. Try tapping it and you'll get nothing.